# c++ parsing binary message library with bit fields

Tags: c++, parsing, flatbuffers, kaitai-struct

Hi is there any descent binary parser AND builder library with support of bit fields in schema( I mean fields in the protocol which have arbitrary bit length and not standard int 32 bits or such). Protobuf and Flatbuffers does not seam to support it. Kaitai is only parser but not packet builder.

Comment: Why do you care how it is serialized to binary? Space consideration?

Comment: Yes and also legacy protocol integration.

Comment: But in the end, I guess, you gonna send it on wire or save to disk, both of which work with bytes, you cant send/save only two bits, moreover, bitfields aligned in memory, so if you have two bitfields of two bits each it will end occupying, say 32 bits in memory

Comment: Technically, Kaitai Struct has writing (building) support in [serialization branch](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_compiler/tree/serialization) under development.